# How do I set a field to DBNull in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, dbnull

How do you set a field to DBNull in Entity Framework?  The fields are strongly typed so you cannot set it equal to DBNull.Value and I did not find any method to set a field to DBNull.  It seems like this is a necessary thing to do, but after much Google research I found nothing about it.

I am trying to set a datetime field in Entity Framework using vb.net. This requires me to write

```
 myEntity.mydate = Nothing
```

This does not set the field to null but instead sets it to the default date value which is not a valid date value in SQL Server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a column is nullable in the database the result class will have a nullable property too.

For example if a `Order` table has a nullable `Datetime` column called `CreatedDate`, then the resulting `Order` class will looks something like this:

```
public partial class Order: EntityObject
{
  ...
  private DateTime? _createdDate;
  ...
}
```

If the _`createdDate` has no value when you call `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()` a `System.DBNull` will automatically be sent to the database as part of insert or update command.

Hope this helps
Alex

Comment: Yes that is correct Alex.  The problem was on my side.  A field which I thought was nullable was not.

Answer (score 10):

Set the field value to `null`.  The Entity Framework will translate this to `System.DBNull`.

Comment: First you should accept null values on the appropriate database field value.

Comment: I am using vb.net which does not have Nulls.  I have to use Nothing instead which sets the date to the default value instead of Null.

Comment: @Eric VB.NET "Nothing" is C#'s "null"

Comment: This didnt work for me, No issue was occurred.row was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

I never used entity-framework but can you turn a variable into a nullable type?

something like

```
dim entityVar as nullable(of date)
```

then you can do the =nothing and it will stay nothing.

but like I said, I never used entity-framework

while looking on google I found that [bug report on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=432777)

Comment: I set it to nullable in the model.designer.vb file but that still doesn't set it to null in the database. That bug report is similar to my problem.  There must be a way to do this. You wouldn't think they would release entity framework without the ability to set database values to null in vb.net.