# How to really check if something is null in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have an entity with a NrPeso decimal property that can be saved in the database as 0 or null.
Here is what I'm doing to assign the value to the property:

```
entity.NrPeso = Convert.ToDecimal(object.value("value"))
```

The problem is: if I don't fill the object value, it's set to `Nothing`. When I do the cast it turns into 0. But I don't want 0, I want `Nothing`. If I compare the object value with `Nothing` it will return me `Nothing` if it is Nothing or 0.

I tought in a few alternatives but they don't seem good.

So, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: If `NrPeso` is of Decimal type then it can't be assigned Null value anyway, so can't see the point here.

Comment: _"I have an entity"_ means you're using Entity-Franmework? Then this is a duplicate of [How do I set a field to DBNull in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820752/how-do-i-set-a-field-to-dbnull-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Decimal` is a structure - is cannot be `Nothing` by definition.

You need a *nullable* `Decimal`.

If `NrPeso` is defined as `Nullable(Of Decimal)` (aka `Decimal?`), things should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distinguish between `0` and `Nothing` when using `Decimal` (or any other value type), you should use a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) in the first place.

So use `Decimal?` instead of `Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim obj As Object = object.value("value")
entity.NrPeso = If (obj Is Nothing, Nothing, Convert.ToDecimal (obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Convert.ToDecimal, consider using Decimal.TryParse and then in a failure condition explicitly set the Nullable type to Null:

```
Dim outVal As Decimal?
If Decimal.TryParse(object.value("value"), outVal)
   entity.NrPeso = outVal
Else
   entity.NrPeso = Nothing
End If
```

Additionally, consider setting Option Strict On in your project to avoid type issues like this in the future.